# dbWriteTable function in DBI package is throwing an error

Tags: r, rjdbc

I am trying to use dbWriteTable function in DBI package to upload a dataframe to presto server. It is throwing the following error:

> "Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC tables list") : 
>     Unable to retrieve JDBC tables list ()"

I have also tried using insert into, create, drop commands in dbSendQuery with the same connection and it is working perfectly. I am facing issue when I use dbWriteTable function.

I have tried other functions of the DBI package like dbReadTable, dbCreateTable too which is working perfectly for me

Code:

```
dbWriteTable(conn,DBI::SQL("test.demo"),value =  df)
```

Comment: Check permissions of connected user. `dbWriteTable` performs `DROP` and `CREATE` commands. Are you allowed these two actions on that schema?

Comment: I have both read and write access to this schema. I have tried using insert into, create, drop commands in dbSendQuery and it is working perfectly. The problem is with dbWriteTable function. I have tried other functions of the DBI package like dbReadTable, dbCreateTable too which is working perfectly.

Comment: Hadley Wickham recommends the [_RPresto_ package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPresto/index.html): https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/1082422935154028544

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is `dbListTables()`. The error probably comes from here:

https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/blob/1a4fa8558bd20b5a6adbdd6588aa1f61bd51d7d7/R/class.R#L273
https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/blob/1a4fa8558bd20b5a6adbdd6588aa1f61bd51d7d7/R/class.R#L183

Does this succeed?

```r
dbListTables(conn, pattern = DBI::SQL("test.demo"))
```

If don't, maybe you don't have permission to read metadata, or something is wrong with your JDBC driver.

(I also recommend RPresto if it works. But, I know it's not always the case...)